# How to add external js files in shopware6.4

Tags: shopware

i am new in  shopware 6.4.
I want to subscribe newsletter for  that i try to import external js file.
Can anyone have idea about how to import external js file in plugins.
any clue have great help for me.

Comment: Do you want to add your js functionality to the storefront or administration? The docs should be a good starting point for you: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript

Comment: Hello i want to use it in storefront. like load 3rd party js files in my plugins.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript is more about importing javascript files that you have locally.

If your script is hosted by a 3rd parts, one option would be to use

```
<script src="https://example.com/external-js-file.min.js"> in your template.
```

You can extend the block

```
{% block layout_head_javascript_feature %}
```

and add your script tag there.