# Shopware 6 integrate google maps in storefront modal

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-maps-api-3, shopware

I am trying to integrate Google maps in a shopware PseudoModalUtil modal window. I then have to add the marker cluster library and add a few clusters.

The thing is, the Google maps API and the marker cluster library are JavaScript files that are normally fetched from a URL, hence the script tag.

However, I don't want to add random script tags in my twig templates, as I am sure nobody would. I guess my two left options would be:

- Either create two distinct JS files for the Google maps API JS response and marker cluster JS response respectively, and then include them in my storefront JS module.
- Or try to install them as web-pack modules and include them in my storefront module. But I think I need to add a package.json file somewhere, and them somehow use web-pack to install everything and include installed modules.

I do not know which approach, if any of these two, is good. I did not find anything in the developer documentation for shopware 6, and on the slack channel nobody seems to answer this question.

I found two links here that are somewhat useful:

- One that shows how to do this for the administration side: [How to add third-party dependency javascript to Shopware 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841395/how-to-add-third-party-dependency-javascript-to-shopware-6)
- The other is how to do this in webpack generally: [How to import static url using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424765/how-to-import-static-url-using-webpack)

I think that's about it.

Comment: It's a very good question. I don't know why it was closed. I think what you are asking is how to integrate 3rd party Javascript code properly? There is a node-js-package of the maps api: https://medium.com/@paw145/using-the-google-maps-api-with-webpack-npm-and-a-handy-promise-returning-helper-19c9312971b0 - but I also do not know in which package.json to require this. I actually think the approach to load the scripts from google directly via script tags is also not too bad - but I hope this question will be reopend.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174012/how-to-add-external-js-files-in-shopware6-4

Comment: I recommend using @googlemaps/js-api-loader https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader

Comment: Did @jpoehnelt's suggestion work?

Comment: The feature was removed, I did not try this further.